# Replacing numbers into a certain format using Notepadd++

Tags: replace, numbers, find, notepad++

I am trying to replace some numbers with - signs into some other format using notepad++

For example

```
-4399.10 changed to 439910}
4399.10  changed to 439919{
-2303.29 changed to 230329}
2303.29  changed to 230329{

all negative signs will be changed to } symbol from right
all positive will be replaced with {
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `ctrl + h` ?

Comment: Ctrl H will require a lot of find and replace. - sign will be replaced }

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional replacement in Notepad++

`Find what`: `(?<negative>-)?(\d+(\.\d+)?)`
`Replace with`: `\2?{negative}}:{`

```
\2?{negative}}:{
\2                 the captured number without sign in group 2
  ?{negative}      if group negative (negative sign) is matched
             }       character }
              :    else
               {     character {
```

The named group is optional i.e. `\2?{1}}:{` or even `\2?1}:{` works the same.
Remember to modify the regex in Find what to wholy match your format.

Comment: You're close, but this keeps the negative sign.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that, but it should be an easy fix. P/s: fixed

Comment: Don't worry, I give you +1.